# How to get traffic statistics on RSS feed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss, sitecore, sitecore6

We are generating our RSS feed on the fly using [Sitecore CMS](http://www.sitecore.net/).

What would be the best possible way to get traffic statistics (i.e. tracking) on RSS Feed?

Solutions which I am looking into right now are:

1. Use a redirect page to your RSS feed and add your Google Analytics code on this redirect page.
2. [Tracking Image](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/06/10/773.aspx). Not sure about this solution.
3. Log hits into database based on IP address, browser information etc.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are looking for is "hits" against your feed, you should be able to get that out of the IIS logs.